# Unable to take picture with Xamarin and MvvmCross on iOS

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm working on an iOS app, which needs to be able to take a picture (to do some stuff with).

I'm using Xamarin with MvvmCross 6.2.0 and have imported the MvxPictureChooser plugin.

I have added NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription to my Info.plist

```
...
<key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs to be able to save your expense attachments as images.</string>
<key>UIRequiresFullScreen</key>
<true/>
...
```

Now, when I try to use the ChoosePictureFromLibrary, all goes well.

If, on the other hand, I try to use TakePicture(int, int, Action, Action), I get an Exception which contains the error: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: Source type 1 not available

My code looks like this:

```
private void DoTakePictureCommand()
    {
        var picChooser = Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<IMvxPictureChooserTask>();
        try
        {
            picChooser.TakePicture(_envProvider.Environment.JpegSize, _envProvider.Environment.JpegQuality, (stream) =>
            {
                using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    stream.CopyToAsync(ms);
                    ReceiptJpegData = ms.ToArray();

                    _log.Trace("Picture bytes: {0}", ReceiptJpegData.Length);

                    InvokeOnMainThread(ImageComplete);
                }
            }, () =>
            {

            });
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.Write(e);
        }
    }
```

The complete error is here:

> [0:] Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: Source type 1 not available
>   Native stack trace:
>
> 0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011c41429b __exceptionPreprocess + 331
>     1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000011d2e8735 objc_exception_throw + 48
>     2   UIKitCore                           0x0000000126d03553 -[UIImagePickerController sourceType] + 0
>     3   xxxiOS                 0x000000010ed801b9 xamarin_dyn_objc_msgSend + 217
>     4   ???                                 0x0000000141e58257 0x0 + 5400527447
>
> > at ObjCRuntime.Runtime.ThrowNSException (System.IntPtr ns_exception) [0x00000] in
> >     /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.0.0.15/src/Xamarin.iOS/ObjCRuntime/Runtime.cs:398
> >
> > at ObjCRuntime.Runtime.throw_ns_exception (System.IntPtr exc) [0x00000] in
> >     /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/runtime/Delegates.generated.cs:126
> >
> > at (wrapper native-to-managed) ObjCRuntime.Runtime.throw_ns_exception(intptr)
> >     --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at (wrapper managed-to-native)
> >     ObjCRuntime.Messaging.void_objc_msgSend_Int64(intptr,intptr,long)   at
> >     UIKit.UIImagePickerController.set_SourceType
> >     (UIKit.UIImagePickerControllerSourceType value) [0x00015] in
> >     /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/12.0.0.15/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIImagePickerController.g.cs:587
> >     at
> >     MvvmCross.Plugin.PictureChooser.Platforms.Ios.MvxImagePickerTask.TakePicture
> >     (System.Int32 maxPixelDimension, System.Int32 percentQuality,
> >     System.Action`1[T] pictureAvailable, System.Action assumeCancelled)
> >     [0x00014] in <8539a731432e4b45b49dd5ca22de5afd>:0    at
> >     xxx.DoTakePictureCommand
> >     () [0x0000d] in
> >     C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\IdeaProjects\xxxx\xxxx\XXX.Core\ViewModels\AddExpenseViewModel.cs:447
> >       0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011c41429b
> >     __exceptionPreprocess + 331   1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000011d2e8735 objc_exception_throw + 48    2   UIKitCore
> >     0x0000000126d03553 -[UIImagePickerController sourceType] + 0  3
> >     xxxiOS                 0x000000010ed801b9
> >     xamarin_dyn_objc_msgSend + 217    4   ???
> >     0x0000000141e58257 0x0 + 5400527447 2018-09-27 23:15:03.294036+0200
> >     xxxiOS[46563:4418172] 2018-09-27 11:15:03 [TRACE]
> >     (MvvmCross.Logging.MvxLog) iOSNavigation 2018-09-27
> >     23:15:03.294886+0200 xxxiOS[46563:4418172] 2018-09-27
> >     11:15:03 [TRACE] (MvvmCross.Logging.MvxLog) PresentationAttribute not
> >     found for AddExpenseView. Assuming animated Child presentation
> >     CalabashServer | XTC_SKIP_LPSERVER_TOKEN is not in the app environment
> >     CalabashServer | Will start LPServer with identifier:
> >     c36c12ce937d044d55d0c208f9d4502868233513

**UPDATE**

I have now tried deploying the code to my iPhone 7 which has been updated to iOS 12, and the app crashes as soon as it attempts to start the camera.

I have also tried hardcoding the int values:

```
private void DoTakePictureCommand()
{
    var picChooser = Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<IMvxPictureChooserTask>();
    try
    {
        picChooser.TakePicture(640, 50, (stream) =>
        {
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                stream.CopyToAsync(ms);
                ReceiptJpegData = ms.ToArray();

                _log.Trace("Picture bytes: {0}", ReceiptJpegData.Length);

                InvokeOnMainThread(ImageComplete);
            }
        }, () =>
        {

        });
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.Write(e);
    }
}
```

But the result is the same.

**UPDATE**

I created a small sample project which replicates the problem. The app uses both choose picture and take picture - only choose picture works. I have posted it to a public repo on Github: [PictureApp](https://github.com/jethoraz/MvvmCross/tree/master/PictureApp)

Comment: are you testing this on a physical device?

Comment: no, I'm testing using an iPhoneSimulator.

Comment: I would assume that's the problem, then.  I don't believe the simulator has a working camera

Comment: Unfortunately it does not appear to be the problem. The app crashes on my phone as soon as TakePicture is invoked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, nailed it!

I'll leave a solution here for other app-developer newbies, who run into this issue.

The solution to the problem was actually quite simple: All I had to do, was add

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string></string>
```

to Info.plist.

It wasn't until I decided to drop MvvmCross.Plugin.PictureChooser and use Xam.Plugin.Media instead, that I got an understandable error message - basically something along the lines of: "you need to add NSCameraUsageDescription to Info.plist since iOS 10"

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is related to the variables you are passing, check if it is not null and its type is `int`.

```
_envProvider.Environment.JpegSize, 
_envProvider.Environment.JpegQuality,
```

From the [docs](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/plugins/picturechooser):

```
 void TakePicture(int maxPixelDimension, int percentQuality, Action<Stream> pictureAvailable,
                     Action assumeCancelled);
```

Comment: I tried with hardcoded int values (as seen in my update on the post), but I'm getting the same result.